# Ubuntu 12.04 takes long time to show desktop

Tags: 12.04, boot, lightdm, desktop-environments

I am creating an application by customizing Ubuntu 12.04.
And i'm using remastersys to create its backup to be distributed,
the customizations are,

1. My Application (Java) installed
2. Postgresql
3. ubuntu user (and password)
4. user auto login
5. using lightdm
6. user session using gnome-classic (no effects)
7. user desktop cleaned-up, i removed all gnome-panel except the last one, empty panel.
8. startup application, python with gtk.
9. root crontab to ensure my application is running (start it otherwise)

My problem is, on the master computer where i originally developing, the boot sequence is not problem,
from BIOS to show the desktop (and my startup apps running) took about 50 seconds. BUT, after doing remastersys
and install it into the other computer, with same specification and same computer model, it takes
about 2 minutes (or even more) to show the user desktop (every other thing is replicated fine).

It boots from BIOS, and then showing the ubuntu-dots loading, after that it looks like hangs untill about 2 minutes,
before the desktop wallpaper shown and my app running (startup application).

What have i tried to resolve this on the target computer (the one installed from remastersys iso)

1. remove all desktop configuration, such as `mv /home/user /home/user.old`, `mkdir /home/user`, `chown user /home/user`, reboot.
   this step makes the desktop customization lost and my startup app not running, but still takes about 2 minutes to show the desktop
2. `apt-get purge unity unity-2d`, still, takes about 2 minutes
3. `apt-get purge compiz`, no luck.
4. set metacity compositing, no luck.
5. removed root's cron, no luck.

And still, the booting time until the desktop is usable is taking about 2 minutes, compared to its original about 40-50 seconds only.
The different is at the moment when the desktop is about to be shown. The ubuntu-dots loading time is about the same.

Please help on this, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried including and running bootchart (included in the 'bootchart' package) on the new system? It is a great tool for discovering the reasons behind slow boots.

Comment: Could you install `bootchart` and attaching the image to your post?

Comment: When it is loading, click alt+tab key a few times. It shows what it is doing in the background. Let us know where it is stopping for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can press ESC while is loading (showing the ubuntu-dots loading) and see what's happening...

or you can switch to other distro maker like https://github.com/clearkimura/Customizer